# OrientDB SQL recursivness

Tags: sql, orientdb, foaf

I have a working query, that returns all the co actors of Tom Hanks (basically a *friend of a friend* problem).

```
  SELECT COUNT(name) as name FROM (
    SELECT expand(out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN')) FROM Actor WHERE name = 'Tom Hanks'
) WHERE name <> 'Tom Hanks'
```

Now I'm trying to construct a query that would give me co actors of co actors (friends of friends of friend)

My query, that doesn't finish

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(name)) as coactor FROM (
SELECT expand(out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN').out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN').out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN')) FROM Person WHERE name = 'Tom Hanks'
)
WHERE name <> 'Tom Hanks'
```

The question is, can you stack *.in* and *.out* like this:

```
expand(out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN').out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN').out('ACTS_IN').in('ACTS_IN'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could use the `TRAVERSE()` function to retrieve all the records linked by the edge `ACTS_IN`.

**Structure**:

```
create class Person extends V
create class Movie extends V
create class acts_In extends E
create class directed extends E
create class friend extends E
create class rated extends E

create property Person.name String
create property Person.surname String
create property Movie.title String

create vertex Person set name="Tom", surname="Hanks"
create vertex Person set name="Robin", surname="Wright"
create vertex Person set name="Helen", surname="Hunt"
create vertex Person set name="Robert", surname="Zemeckis"
create vertex Person set name="Russell", surname="Crowe"
create vertex Person set name="Ben", surname="Affleck"
create vertex Person set name="Kevin", surname="Macdonald"
create vertex Person set name="John"
create vertex Person set name="Mark"
create vertex Person set name="Paul"
create vertex Person set name="Mel", surname="Gibson"
create vertex Person set name="Nancy", surname="Meyers"
create vertex Movie set title="Forrest Gump"
create vertex Movie set title="Cast Away"
create vertex Movie set title="State of Play"
create vertex Movie set title="What Women Want"

create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Tom" and surname="Hanks") to (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Tom" and surname="Hanks") to (select from Movie where title="Cast Away")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Robin" and surname="Wright") to (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Robin" and surname="Wright") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt") to (select from Movie where title="Cast Away")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt") to (select from Movie where title="What Women Want")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Mel" and surname="Gibson") to (select from Movie where title="What Women Want")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Russell" and surname="Crowe") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge acts_In from (select from Person where name="Ben" and surname="Affleck") to (select from Movie where title="State of Play")
create edge friend from (select from Person where name="Mel" and surname="Gibson") to (select from Person where name="Helen" and surname="Hunt")
create edge friend from (select from Person where name="Ben" and surname="Affleck") to (select from Person where name="Russell" and surname="Crowe")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="What Women Want") to (select from Person where name="Nancy" and surname="Meyers")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="Cast Away") to (select from Person where name="Robert" and surname="Zemeckis")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump") to (select from Person where name="Robert" and surname="Zemeckis")
create edge directed from (select from Movie where title="State of Play") to (select from Person where name="Kevin" and surname="Macdonald")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="What Women Want") to (select from Person where name="Paul")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="Cast Away") to (select from Person where name="John")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="Forrest Gump") to (select from Person where name="Mark")
create edge rated from (select from Movie where title="State of Play") to (select from Person where name="John")
```

**Query 1**: Retrieve all of the actors/co-actors/ecc... of 'Tom Hanks' (except himself)

```
SELECT expand(DISTINCT) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(@rid) FROM (TRAVERSE BOTH('ACTS_IN') 
FROM (SELECT FROM Person WHERE name = 'Tom' AND surname = 'Hanks') MAXDEPTH 4) 
WHERE name <> 'Tom' and surname <> 'Hanks')
```

**Query 2**: Retrieve the count of the actors/co-actors/ecc... of 'Tom Hanks' (except himself)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(@rid)) AS co_actors FROM (TRAVERSE BOTH('ACTS_IN') 
FROM (SELECT FROM Person WHERE name = 'Tom' AND surname = 'Hanks') MAXDEPTH 4) 
WHERE name <> 'Tom' and surname <> 'Hanks'
```

Comment: `TRAVERSE()` function visits all connected nodes. Can you somehow limit the depth (hops that it takes) for traversing? For example, this query now returns all the nodes in the graph for Tom Hanks (3 hops is all it takes). While I would like to limit the query to 2 hops?

Comment: Hi, I've just edited my answer with the setting of `$depth` that stops the `TRAVERSE()` at the level that you want.

Comment: Hey Luca, thanks. But `$depth` doesn't do anything in my (your case). The results, or count, stays always the same: 50177 (all nodes). Could it be that `$depth` is actually looking for completely different condition to be met? I tried depth value of 1, 2, 3, 4. And it always traverses whole graph.

Comment: Hi Blaz, I edited both queries and added my structure for a better explanation. I checked and I think that the best way is to use the `MAXDEPTH` operator which considers the specified level -1 (in this case from 0 to 3). I hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Thank you, this will do.